# execute linux commands from php scripts

Tags: php, linux, command-line, command, exec

Good day to all.

I need to send a request to a script and then to execute some commands (basically I need to start ffmpeg when clicking on a link).

I tried this:

```
exec("ffserver &");
exec("ffmpeg -i pipe.avi output.avi");
exec("mplayer -dumpstream someinput -dumpfile pipe.avi");
```

and this

```
shell_exec("ffserver &");
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i pipe.avi output.avi");
shell_exec("mplayer -dumpstream someinput -dumpfile pipe.avi");
```

In both cases I got timeout. Can any1 help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Note: Seems like after running the shell variant I get timeout whatever I do :| so... can any1 also add a note how do I repair my php parser? (if not i'll just reinstall apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, its has been posted by user **bahri at bahri dot info** as a comment to the PHP manual entry for [**exec**](http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php)

```
<?php
  function PsExecute($command, $timeout = 60, $sleep = 2) {
        // First, execute the process, get the process ID

        $pid = PsExec($command);

        if( $pid === false )
            return false;

        $cur = 0;
        // Second, loop for $timeout seconds checking if process is running
        while( $cur < $timeout ) {
            sleep($sleep);
            $cur += $sleep;
            // If process is no longer running, return true;

           echo "\n ---- $cur ------ \n";

            if( !PsExists($pid) )
                return true; // Process must have exited, success!
        }

        // If process is still running after timeout, kill the process and return false
        PsKill($pid);
        return false;
    }

    function PsExec($commandJob) {

        $command = $commandJob.' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!';
        exec($command ,$op);
        $pid = (int)$op[0];

        if($pid!="") return $pid;

        return false;
    }

    function PsExists($pid) {

        exec("ps ax | grep $pid 2>&1", $output);

        while( list(,$row) = each($output) ) {

                $row_array = explode(" ", $row);
                $check_pid = $row_array[0];

                if($pid == $check_pid) {
                        return true;
                }

        }

        return false;
    }

    function PsKill($pid) {
        exec("kill -9 $pid", $output);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'll try it in a min... just after I repair apache :).

Answer (score 1):

If this is only a timeout error, try putting set_time_limit(xx); on top of your code.
With xx corresponding to the time to wait in seconds.

Putting 0 means no time limit, but it may be endless if your script enters an infinite loop, of if it is waiting a feedback from your encoding command that never arrives...

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase PHP script execution time in your `php.ini` file or by setting the function [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)